# Point multiple domain names to one website in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to point multiple URLs to the same website on Magento 2? I have 2 urls, both of which should open the same website. I have tried adding a case in index.php which points to an existing website's code.

```
case 'abc.example.in':
     $mageRunCode = 'abc_web';
     $mageRunType = 'website';
     break;
case 'pqr.example.in':
     $mageRunCode = 'abc_web';
     $mageRunType = 'website';
     break;
```

In base link url of the website(abc_web) I have put `https://abc.example.in`. When I try opening `https://pqr.example.com`, it does open the website but in the url it shows `https://abc.example.in`. I want `https://pqr.example.com`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$params = $_SERVER;
$domain2store = array(
    'domain.at'=>'at',
    'domain.ch'=>'ch',
    'domain.es'=>'es'
    );
if(isset($domain2store[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]))
    $storecode = $domain2store[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($storecode) ? $storecode : '';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Thats how we made it.

Comment: I think this is for redirecting to different stores in a multi store website. I want to point the two urls to a website which has only one store.